# Plotting of a 2D-System of Nonlinear ODEs

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

I am trying to numerically solve and plot the solution curves $p_i(t) = (x_i(t),y_i(t))$ for $i = 1, 2$ and $3$ of the following system of nonlinear differential equations:

```
p1[t_] := {x1[t], y1[t]}

p2[t_] := {x2[t], y2[t]}

p3[t_] := {x3[t], y3[t]}

A1[a_, b_, t_] := a*(p2[t] - p1[t])*Exp[b*(p1[t] - p2[t])]*(p2[t] - p1[t])/Norm[p2[t] - p1[t]]

R1[c_, t_] := c/(p2[t] - p1[t])*(p2[t] - p1[t])/Norm[p2[t] - p1[t]]

B1[a_, b_, c_, t_] := A1[a, b, t] - R1[c, t]

A2[a_, b_, t_] :=  a*(p3[t] - p1[t])*Exp[b*(p1[t] - p3[t])]*(p3[t] - p1[t])/Norm[p3[t] - p1[t]]

R2[c_, t_] := c/(p3[t] - p1[t])*(p3[t] - p1[t])/Norm[p3[t] - p1[t]]

B2[a_, b_, c_, t_] := A2[a, b, t] - R2[c, t]

A3[a_, b_, t_] :=  a*(p3[t] - p2[t])*Exp[b*(p2[t] - p3[t])]*(p3[t] - p2[t])/Norm[p3[t] - p2[t]]

R3[c_, t_] := c/(p3[t] - p2[t])*(p3[t] - p2[t])/Norm[p3[t] - p2[t]]

B3[a_, b_, c_, t_] := A3[a, b, t] - R3[c, t]

sls = ParametricNDSolveValue[{p1'[t] == B1[a, b, c, t] + B2[a, b, c, t], p2'[t] == B3[a, b, c, t] - B1[a, b, c, t], p3'[t] == -B2[a, b, c, t] - B3[a, b, c, t], p1[0] == {-1, -1}, p2[0] == {0, 0}, p3[0] == {1, 1}}, {p1, p2, p3}, {t, 0, 100}, {a, b, c}]
```

However, no functions were specified for output from NDSolveValue. How do I make a plot of the $p_i(t)$ where the coordinates $x_i(t)$ are plotted against the coordinates $y_i(t)$? Any helps are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to fix your code is to remove

```
p1[t_] := {x1[t], y1[t]};

p2[t_] := {x2[t], y2[t]};

p3[t_] := {x3[t], y3[t]};
```

from your code (don't forget to `Clear[p1,p2,p3]`). Next you just need e.g.:

```
ParametricPlot[sls[1, 1, 1][[1]][t], {t, 0, 100}]
```

To plot them all in once you can

```
ParametricPlot[sls[1, 1, 1][t] // Through // Evaluate, {t, 0, 100}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Answer (score 1):

For example for parameter values $a=b=c=1$:

`sls1 = sls[1, 1, 1];`

`GraphicsRow[
 Table[ParametricPlot[(sls1 /. t -> s)[[i]], {s, 0, 100}], {i, 1, 3}]]`

[image]

You can also visualize the parameter range with

`Manipulate[
 GraphicsRow[
  Table[ParametricPlot[(sls[a, b, c] /. t -> s)[[i]], {s, 0, 
     100}], {i, 1, 3}]],
 {a, 0, 10}, {b, 0, 10}, {c, 0, 10}]`

Comment: Unfortuntely, Mathematica gives me interpolating functions if I replace {p1,p2,p3} with {x1,y1,x2,y2,z3,y3}. Did you manage to run it without errors?

Comment: Do you get errors if you run the `Manipulate` command above?

Comment: Yes, I even get an error for running the sls command.

Comment: In defining `sls` make sure you use `{p1[t], p2[t], p3[t]}` as the solution targets as opposed to just `{p1, p2, p3}`.

Comment: You can get them even in one picture by using  Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[Evaluate[sls[a, b, c]], {t, 0, T}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-10, 10}, {-10, 10}}, ImageSize -> Large, 
  AspectRatio -> 1], {{T, 1}, 0, 100}, {{a, 1}, 0, 10}, {{b, 1}, 0, 
  10}, {{c, 1}, 0, 10}]. Thanks for your and ulvi's efforts. Btw, how do you type in commands when replying someone?

Comment: My next question is how we can include all initial values in the code I mentioned above to get a direction field?

Comment: @E4M2227601 As to comment formatting, check [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting). We already have a number of posts about direction field,  just search in this site.